# Ouya build experiencing odd graphical artifacts, screen half black

Tags: unity, ouya

I'm witnessing very odd graphical artifacts when I run my Unity game on Ouya. After the Unity splash screen, the game loads with the screen half black.

[image]

This seemingly has started occurring out of the blue. It also doesn't occur in the editor or the standalone build, only on Ouya. I can't think of a single reason why this would be happening. If I open the Ouya menu screen and close it, the game returns to normal; somewhat, as there may be some artifacts lingering but the screen isn't half black like in the screen shot above.

I know there's not much to go off of, but any insight into why this may be happening is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using too much VRAM?

Comment: I don't think so. According to the stats window in the Unity editor, I'm only using 21.5MB to 30.4MB VRAM.

Comment: Sorry... If that's not it, I can't help you there... I don't have any experience with the Ouya (yet).